# cakephp 3.0 routing issue

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I am facing issue in cakephp3. In `routes.php` I have used

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
     $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'TblUsers', 'action' => 'index']);
});
```

I have placed the `TblUsers` inside `Admin` folder

In app controller code:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'username',
                //'password' => 'password'
            ],
            'scope' => ['role' => '1']
        ]
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login',
        'admin'=>true,
        'prefix'=>true

    ],
    'redirectUrl' => [
        'controller' => 'TblUsers',
        'action' => 'index',
        'admin'=>true,

    ],
    'loginRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'TblUsers',
        'action' => 'index',
        'admin'=>true,

    ]
]);
```

Now when I access the users/login its giving me error:

> Error: A route matching "array ( 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true, 'prefix' => true, 'plugin' => NULL, '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found.

OR

Is there any way in cakephp3 like cakephp2 to access the functions inside any controller start with `admin_functionname` and call the `admin_functionname.ctp` file and also add the admin inside the url.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your prefix to the actual prefix, not `true`.

So change this;

```
'loginAction' => [
    'controller' => 'Users',
    'action' => 'login',
    'admin'=>true,
    'prefix'=>true
```

To this;

```
'loginAction' => [
    'controller' => 'Users',
    'action' => 'login',
    'prefix'=> 'admin'
```

You'll need to do the same with your loginRedirect and redirectUrl

You can find more information here http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 0):

**This example is for Simple page with Admin Panel:**

Structure fodlers and files:

```
src
_Controller
 _admin
   __AppController.php
   __UsersController.php
   __OtherAdminController.php
 _AppController.php
 _UsersController.php
 _OtherPublicController.php

_Template
 _admin
  __Users
    _login.ctp
    _add.ctp
    _etc.ctp
  __OtherAdminTemplate
 _Users
 _Pages
 _etc
```

**config/routes.php**

```
Router::prefix('admin', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

  $routes->connect('/',['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
  $routes->connect('/:controller',['action' => 'index'],['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);
  $routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*',[], ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);

});
```

**Controller/Admin/AppController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Admin; // <---- Name your admin folder

use App\Controller\AppController as Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
/**
 * App Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\AppTable $App
 */
class AppController extends Controller
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'))
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'prefix' => false,
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'home',
            ),
        ));

        $this->Auth->deny();

    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        // If you want use admin.ctp layout
        if ($this->request->params['prefix'] === 'admin') {
             $this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');
        }
        //Autorized acctions without registration   
        $this->Auth->allow(['forgotPassword', 'resetPassword']);

    }

}
```

**Controller/Admin/UsersController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Admin; // <---- Name your admin folder

use App\Controller\Admin\AppController;  // <---- Name your admin folder
use Cake\Mailer\Email;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function login() 
        {
      //Admin Login function
        }

    //Rest of Users admin functions
}
```